# Filter sql records based on a json stored as string value in a column?

Tags: sql, json, presto, amazon-athena

I have a sql table with rows
roll_num(int),name(string),class(string),marks(string).
The marks column stores string thats actually a json for ex

```
{
"english":25,
"maths":30,
"science":78
}
```

Now for example
I want all the rows where maths marks are greater than 30.
Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: at least try something out

Answer (score 0):

To extract the properties from the JSON string, use the ***json_extract*** function.

Sample code :

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT '{
"english":25,
"maths":30,

"science":78
}'
    AS jsondata
)
SELECT
  json_extract(jsondata, '$.english') AS english,
  json_extract(jsondata, '$.maths') AS maths,
  json_extract(jsondata, '$.science') AS science
FROM dataset
```

Output :

```
    english maths   science
1     25     30       78
```

For details on working with json strings in athena refer following AWS documentation:

[Extracting data from json string in athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/extracting-data-from-JSON.html)